# Unknown Host exception while connecting to Database using Selenium

Tags: java, database, selenium-webdriver, automation, ssl-certificate

When I am connected to the client network (using VPN) then i am successfully able to fetch the data from the database. But if I disconnect from the client network and run locally the same function then I am getting below error -

**Connection Failed:SAP DBTech JDBC: Cannot connect to jdbc:sap://saphsg.XXXX.XX.com:30015 [Unknown host saphsg.XXXX.XXX.com:30015 [null], -709].**

Below is the code which i am using -

```
public static void dbConnection(String query) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {                  
            Class.forName("com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sap://saphsg.XXXX.XXX.com:30015?encrypt=true&validateCertificate=false", UserID, Password);                             
        
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Connection Failed:" +e.getMessage());
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Connection to HANA successful!");
                Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                while (resultSet.next()){
                    String Name1 = resultSet.getString(1);                                      
                    String Name2 = resultSet.getString(4);  
                    String Name3 = resultSet.getString(5);  
                    System. out.println(Name1+"----"+Name2+"----"+Name3);       
                }       
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.err.println("Query failed!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you manually able to connect to HANA db t check if your jdbc connection string is correct

Comment: without VPN im not able to connect it manually

Comment: Then you have to set up a proxy